# Deletion of question upon deleting accounts?

Tags: discussion

Does removing your account delete your questions?

What are the mechanisms for having a question deleted?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious about [your question](http://serverfault.com/q/560146/126632) that would warrant deleting it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it is breaking the internet 8-|

Comment: @MichaelHampton the usual unprofessional behavior by moderators here is is why.

Comment: Oh, the sheer irony of making such a claim on the only Stack Exchange site where _all_ the moderators are professionals. Would you care to justify that claim?

Comment: So youre saying a moderator calling users idiots is acceptable professionalism.

Sounds like an argument you would make.

Comment: Did you flag the comment as non-constructive that you didn't like?  Getting directly called an "idiot" isn't acceptable here, but things happen and there are mechanisms in place to handle it.  If the flag doesn't handle it, you can post the issue here in Meta to resolve the "conflict", citing the comment/answer and not posting in Meta a veiled rant.  Even if it is a moderator or high rep user, they can be called out for going over the line, even if their intent was to heavily persuade you towards the "right way".

Comment: Yes. Flagged and was edited by another moderator. The person who edited it was Chris S. Even after moderation vortaq7 was unapologetic and said his comment stands. That is still there to be seen. Person who made the comment: vortaq7. Also this was not a veiled rant. This was a question which got answered. Then of course moderators took it further than that AGAIN within this question. This question never once referenced the dispute. Micheal brought that in on his own accord.

Comment: Now Chris S. Has deleted my own answer which solved my question on this. Saying it in fact didnt solve my issue.

Good to know. You guys are classy individuals. 
Think that pretty much sums up everyones unprofessional behavior here.

Comment: I see modifications by  Michael Hampton, but no comment on wither or not its professional to call people idiots.

Comment: I get your points, but I think you have to understand something that may not sit well (and maybe @MichaelHampton and others will disagree with me on...who knows).  While we would love to say that SF and any site like it is non-partisan and doesn't play favorites, there is going to be some leeway given to users that are VERY active on the site, have unusually high rep, or are moderators.  It's just going to happen.  It's still a system overseen by humans.  You can call out the issue via flag or here in Meta but sometimes it is best to simply ignore a comment you don't like.

Comment: @TheCleaner I never saw the comment in question before it was edited, so I can't really comment on it.

Comment: @TheCleaner This is well understood, and probably what I should of done. However it doesn't negate the fact moderators exist which abuse the system and act un professional. Just like Michael cannot denounce even obvious questions like is calling someone an idiot unprofessional. Then resort to saying that they havnt seen it as some kind of back up defense. Sad that the only answer is that it's best not to interact at all and thats not the way it should be here. But just running away doesnt seem to ever address the issue. So I guess that leaves meta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions and other posts are not removed when your account is deleted [unless they score less than 0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

Questions may be deleted by the Original Poster before upvoted answers are posted.
Once a Question has upvoted answers it's generally considered Community Property (per the license linked at the bottom of every page). So it can't be deleted.

Under unusual circumstance we can delete whole questions or redact parts thereof.

Comment: Note that by "unusual circumstance" we basically mean "Unless you have a ***REALLY*** good reason your question isn't getting deleted." If you would like a question *disassociated* from your account (so nobody knows you're the one who asked it) we can do that for you too - simply flag the question with your request.